# Are $(X+1,X), (X^2+4,5)$ and $(X^2+1,X+2)$ maximal or prime?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

How do I know if $(X+1,X), (X^2+4,5)$ and $(X^2+1,X+2)$ are maximal or prime in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$?

---

I know the definitions of maximal and prime ideal, but I don't know how to do this exercise? Any hint?

If I'm not wrong, $(X+1,X)=(1,X)$ and $(X^2+1,X+2)=(5,X+2)$ but I don't know if this will help me...

Comment: Looking at quotients is helpful. I.e., is $\mathbb Z[X] / I$ an integral domain and/or a field for the different ideals $I$?

Comment: But how can I do that? I mean, for example, in the first case I have to see if $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(1,X)}$ is an integral domain, right? How do I knnow if it is an integral domain or not? (I know the definition of integral domain, I have to do it with the definition?)@prets

Comment: In that particular case, what can you say about an ideal that contains $1$?

Comment: But sure, yes, in general you can absolutely approach these questions by using the definition of integral domain in the quotient.

Comment: Ahhhh, $(1,X)=\mathbb{Z}[X]$, right? So as it is not proper, it is not maximal and it is not prime. True? @prets

Comment: Yep. The other ideals are of course much more interesting.

Comment: But for example, in the second one, I've got that $(X^2+4,5)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ iff $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{(X^2+4,5)}$ is an integral domain. How can I see that with the definition? @prets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131674/discussion-between-prets-and-user160).

Answer (score 1):

I'll write a solution for the middle one. Similar games apply to the other ones---investigate whether the quotients are integral domains, fields, or neither.

We have
$$ \mathbb Z[X] / (X^2 + 4, 5) \simeq (\mathbb Z / 5 \mathbb Z)[X] / (X^2 + 4), $$
so we are considering $X^2 + 4$ as a polynomial in the ring of polynomials with coefficients modulo $5$.
Note that modulo $5$, the polynomial
$$ X^2 + 4 = X^2 - 1 = (X - 1)(X + 1) = (X + 4)(X + 1) $$
factors, so the polynomial is certainly not irreducible, and hence the ideal is definitely not maximal.
But it is also not prime, for the same factorisation tells us that in the quotient $\mathbb Z[X] / (X^2 + 4, 5)$ we have zero divisors!